# Using slf4j logger in a simple mvc Spring web project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logging, slf4j

I am learning spring web mvc project from online resources, i came across this logger slf4j, and i want to use it in my application.

I don't have any idea on how to add this. what i am thinking is i should remove commons-logging.jar from lib folder, and add another jar file to lib folder, but then i don't know which jar file i should add as there are many jar files present in slf4j.zip that i have downloaded from its official site.

I have searched and read few posts/articles about integrating slf4j but they all were related to maven, and i don't have maven, i simply started working with adding spring framework jars to dynamic web project.

Please tell me how and what files i should add in lib folder for logging purpose. or how to configure the slf4j logger.
thanx folks!!

Answer (score 2):

The official source of information on logging in Spring is the [Spring Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-logging).

If you want to use SLF4J, this document suggests using the following Maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In other words, you need four `.jar` files, and you need to make sure that the Commons Logging library is NOT on your classpath.

If you do not use Maven, you can download these `.jar`s from the [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#advancedsearch|gav) manually. Enter `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` on that page, press `Search`, and download the `.jar` file (not `sources.jar`!). Here are direct links to these `.jar` files: [jcl-over-slf4j](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.5.8/jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar), [slf4j-api](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.8/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar), [slf4j-log4j12](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.5.8/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar), [log4j](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=log4j/log4j/1.2.14/log4j-1.2.14.jar).

You will also need to create and put on your classpath the configuration file for log4j (`log4j.xml` or `log4j.properties`).

I think that by not using Maven you make your life harder, not easier. It's better to spend some time learning it, than spend a lot of time trying to avoid learning it.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually argue against using pure SLF4J to begin with, because its own creators have already created a successor.

Reasons to use it instead of SLF4J are given on http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html

And the "First baby steps" in the manual are at http://logback.qos.ch/manual/introduction.html